# Capture DNS request from WebClient response

Tags: c#

I have a dns server setup that currently blocks nearly all dns requests. What I want to do is create a simple application so that I can query a known acceptable website and pull all the failed dns entries called from the website.

For Example, I want to allow twitch.tv. So I add a dns entry for twitch.tv, then I would call the application with twitch.tv and it would list out all the failed dns requests made by twitch.tv (ie api.twitch.tv, chatdepot.twitch.tv, etc). Then I can run those through an outside dns and pull the entries.

The Chrome Network tab shows these as 404 responses, or, sometimes, as 403 responses.

The Question: How do I capture dns requests from a WebClient response in C#?

```
        var url = "http://www.twitch.tv";
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

        var response = request.GetResponse();

        //todo: get requests from site result and test
        var responsestream = response.GetResponseStream();

        using (var reader = new StreamReader(responsestream))
        {
            var responsestring = reader.ReadToEnd();



            Console.Write(responsestring);

        }
```

Comment: Have you got some code? Anything you can show?

Comment: @TheCoolFrood I added where I started, I need to know what requests fail during the page load

Comment: I adjusted the question, if I can just get a list of the requests needed to flesh out the response, I can test those for errors